# Lookup value in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replace the local variables i've declared below to capture them in calculated columns.

So the [YTD] column would look up Today's Date - 1 and return the [FiscalDayOfYear] making everything in that column less than that "YTD" and anything greater "NA"

```
DECLARE @ytd FLOAT = 124
DECLARE @monthly FLOAT = 4

SELECT *
FROM(
 SELECT [Date]
      ,[FiscalDayOfYear]
      ,[FiscalYear]
      ,[FiscalMonthNumber]
      ,[FiscalWeekNumber]
      ,[YTD] = IIF([FiscalDayOfYear] <= @ytd, 'YTD','NA')
      ,[MTD] = IIF(([FiscalDayOfYear] <= @ytd) AND ([FiscalMonthNumber] = @monthly), 'MTD','NA')
  FROM [DL].[Date]
 WHERE  CONVERT(date,Date) >= '2018-01-01') AS DT
UNPIVOT 
(
  [FLAG] FOR FLAGS IN ([YTD], [MTD])
) AS pivoted_tbl
WHERE [FLAG] != 'NA'
```

Because of our fiscal calendar I can't just use the Date column I've got to compare to day of year in our calendar.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your question is, but aside, `float` is rarely the correct data type, probably `int` and `tinyint` are more appropriate.

Comment: I'm trying to create 2 calculated columns, 1 for YTD and 1 for MTD.  Those 2 variables i declared are the values i'm looking to return. But rather than have those manually input i'd like that calculated column to lookup todays date -1 and return the what that fiscal day of year is.

Comment: Do you mean *computed column*? If so what's stopping you and what's the relevance of the query?

Comment: Yes "computed" column. Cleary the how to is stopping me from this. I can't figure out how to lookup a value the date value and return what the corresponding fiscal day is. I'm building a table that will get refreshed daily so those manual input variables won't work.

Comment: A computed column generally can reference columns only in the same row, although it's posisble to use a scalar udf also. I think some sample data and desired results would help clarify what you need.

Comment: A fiscal calendar start date is just some offset from _today_  "FiscalDayOfYear" seems like a simple calculation: (_dayOfCalendarYear_ + _offset_ = _FiscalDayOfYear_)...or am I missing something